# Is it safe to use error codes returned from Facebook API requests?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it safe to do this:

```
FB.api('/me/{something}', function(response) {
    if (response.error) {
        if (response.error.code === some_code) {
            // do something
        } else {
            // do some other things
        }
    }
}, 'post');
```

I could not find those error codes documented anywhere. Have Facebook ever changed an error code without notice?

Answer (score 1):

It is only safe if it is part of the *published API*. Otherwise, if the error codes aren't documented, then you're on your own.

APIs can change but it's unlikely that this would happen *without notice*.